# Python : Maintain the session in order to access all the pages after login

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I'm using python to parse some webpages. I've used beautiful script to parse a login page and send a payload to login:

```
import bs4 as bs 
import urllib.request
import requests
import webbrowser
import urllib.parse

primary_url = "SOME URL YOU WANT TO LOG IN"
sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(primary_url).read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce,"html.parser")

for form_list in soup.find_all('form'):

    action_value = form_list.get('action')
    action_url = urllib.parse.urljoin(primary_url, action_value)
    method_value = form_list.get('method')

    if (method_value == "post"):
        payload = dict()
        inputs1 = form_list.findAll('input',type ="email")
        for i in inputs1:
            input2 = i.get('name')
            script_value = 'USER-EMAIL'
            payload[input2] = script_value
        inputs2 = form_list.findAll('input',type ="password")    
        for j in inputs2:
            input3 = j.get('name')
            script_value = 'PASSWORD-FOR-EMAIL'
            payload[input3] = script_value          

        r = requests.post(action_url, payload)
        with open("result_page.html", "w") as f:
            f.write(str(r.content))
        sessionid = r.cookies.get('SESSIONID') #ERROR
        print(sessionid) #ERROR

# CODE TO ACCESS FURTHER PAGES . . .
```

However I'm not able to access the pages further, because I need to be logged in to access those pages.

Comment: To be able to use cookies in your further requests and still be logged in you should look towards [`requests.session()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects)

Comment: How do I maintain the session until I parse all the pages of the webpage?

Comment: @MaccenWright create a session object.

Comment: A example code to create a session object and use it to maintain the session would be helpful since I'm new to python session handling.

Comment: Use auth = {...} header to access a page which needs authentication. Read the documentation : http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Comment: @DeathJack2.0 Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can re-write your code to solve your stated problem much efficiently using Python Requests.

```
username = "Your Username"
password = "Password"
sauce = requests.get(url, auth=(username, password))
sauce = sauce.content
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce,"html.parser")
print(soup)
```

You need not 'maintain' session in order to gain access to other pages. You can simply send `auth = {username, password}` to every page you want to parse.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `requests.Session()`. Create a `session`, login and parse. You can parse other pages too after login. 
You can read the documentation [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).

```
import bs4 as bs 
import requests
import urllib.parse

primary_url = "SOME URL YOU WANT TO LOG IN"
sess = requests.Session()
sauce = sess.get(primary_url)
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce.text,"html.parser")

for form_list in soup.find_all('form'):

    action_value = form_list.get('action')
    action_url = urllib.parse.urljoin(primary_url, action_value)
    method_value = form_list.get('method')

    if (method_value == "post"):
        payload = dict()

        inputs1 = form_list.find_all('input',type ="email")
        for i in inputs1:
            input2 = i.get('name')
            script_value = 'USER-EMAIL'
            payload[input2] = script_value

        inputs2 = form_list.find_all('input',type ="password")    
        for j in inputs2:
            input3 = j.get('name')
            script_value = 'PASSWORD-FOR-EMAIL'
            payload[input3] = script_value          

        r = sess.post(action_url, data=payload)
        with open("result_page.html", "w") as f:
            f.write(str(r.content))
```

**EDIT** 
To login you need to make a `post` request. Find out the name of `username`, `password` field in the form then create a dictionary and send the data making a `post` request.

Comment: Will this work if I need to parse any other webpage in the website which needs authentication?

Comment: File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.6.0-py3.6.egg/bs4/__init__.py", line 192, in __init__
TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len() : 
This is the error I get. What's the issue? Not able to resolve.

Comment: Can you give my the website link you are scrapping ?

Comment: @MaccenWright I changed a bit from `soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce,"html.parser")` to `soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce.text,"html.parser")`. Try now. Did you login ? I haven't shown the login process.